# Responsive design issue on Iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm creating a responsive chatbot in css boostrap. But when I open the app on an Iphone the header and footer are not fixed, and open keyboard header  was going up the screen. Could someone help me figure out this issue, it only appearson the Iphone, it works fine on android.

Comment: It will be easy to debug and suggest something if you are able to share yout html and css code.

Answer (score 0):

Please make clear, what you re talking about.

Not sure, but
are u talking about the **browser bar**, that gets hidden on the iPhone - in most cases that is the only difference between android and ios.

I had that problem for a web page that used an horizontal scroll effect and was fixed.
When I swiped the page on ios devices the browser tried to hide the bars, got some flickering and jumping side effects.

If that is the case, please try

```
/* Prevent hiding browser bar */
html {
    overflow: hidden!important;
    height:100%!important;
    position:fixed!important; /* prevent overscroll bounce */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important; /* iOS velocity scrolling */
}
```

that helped me.
Hope it ll help you as well.